# Teechart + Bar Color Issues

Tags: activex, teechart

I have created a single Bar Series which have around 2000 pts. After plotting the bar are seen with black color instead of the Series Color.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `Pen.Visible=false`. The minimum size of the pen is 1 and having so many bars, it ends drawing the borders without space for the brushes.